# Strange behaviour of ngDirectives inside custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wrote this directive:

```
app.directive('vvPopover', function($templateCache, $compile){
    return{
        link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.click(function(){
                $(this).parent().append($compile($templateCache.get('notificationPanel'))(scope));

            });    
        }
    }
});
```

That take this template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="notificationPanel">
    <div class="ss-popover" ng-show="false">
        <div>Notifiche</div>
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="notif in [0,1,2]">{{notif}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</script>
```

And put it inside this html:

```
<li class="headerCampaign">
         <button class="icon-bell" vv-popover></button>
</li>
```

The result, as seen through Chrome is:

```
<li class="headerCampaign">
       <button class="icon-bell" vv-popover=""></button>
       <div class="ss-popover ng-binding ng-scope" ng-show="false">
           <div>Notifiche</div>
           <ol>
           <!-- ngRepeat: notif in [0,1,2] -->
           </ol>
       </div>
</li>
```

As you can see, the ng-show directive is not affected by angular. The ng-repeat is compiled but does not iterate through the array.

Any explanation for this weirdness?

Comment: `elem` already `jqLite` objectm you not need wrap it in jQuery

Comment: Have you tried calling `scope.$apply()` after the `$(this).parent().append(...)` line?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thank tou! Can you explain me the reason behind?

Comment: Angular depends on the digest cycle to "sense" changes in watched expressions and call the appropriate watchers. The watched expressions in this case are, e.g. the `[0,1,2]` array and the watchers the `ng-repeat` directive that renders it. `$apply()` triggers the digest cycle and thus the rendering. Angular's built-in directives, such as `ng-click`, call `$apply()` themselves, but when calling Angular "externally" (most notable case: manual event handlers like the `click()` above), you have to call `$apply()` yourself.

Comment: That's so obvious! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `scope.$apply()` inside your click function